# Automating a custom QGraphicsObject control in an external QT based process

Tags: qt, widget, hook, code-injection

I have injected a DLL into an external application that is based on the QT framework. I then use the command QApplication::allWidgets() and iterate through the list of widgets to find a QGraphicsView that represents the window I want to interact with. The buttons and other controls in the scene are all derived from QGraphicsObject. I don't have the source, so I can only cast to QGraphicsObject and not the actual type. The list of methods from the metaobject is incomplete, which is to be expected, because I cast to a QGraphicsObject. I can find the method names using IDA though. Is it possible to call a particular method, and how would you do it?

Comment: If the method is a slot, have you tried calling it with [invokeMethod](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmetaobject.html#invokeMethod)?

Comment: I tried InvokeMethod, but it didn't work. Any other suggestions?